# Log and Exponential Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Hi I tried some old test problems but I don't have any feedback as to whether I'm doing it right could anybody check my solutions

\begin{align}
\log_{3}(x+4) - \log_{3}\left(\frac{1}{x-2}\right) & =  \ln e + \log_{6}36 \\ \log_3(x+4)(x+2) & = 1 + 2 \\ \log_3(x+4)(x+2) & = 3 \\ 
\log_3(x^2+2x-8) & = 3\\ 
x^2+2x-8 &= 3^3\\ 
x^2+2x-8 &= 27\\ 
x^2+2x-8-27 & = 0\\ 
x^2+2x-35 &= 0\\ 
(x+7)(x-5) &= 0
\end{align}

$\therefore\{-7,5\}$ is the solution set.

---

\begin{align*}
32^{2-2x} & = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{x^2-5}\\
(2^5)^{2-2x} & = \left(\frac{1}{2^2}\right)^{x^2-5}\\
2^{10-10x} & = (2^{-2})^{x^2-5}\\
2^{10-10x} & = 2^{-2x^2+10}\\
10-10x & = -2x^2+10\\
-10x & = -2x^2 &&   \text{divide both by $-2x$}\\
\end{align*}

Soln' set $=\{5\}$

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE.  __2__ things: Use [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) to learn how to format via $\LaTeX$ and secondly, 
if someone gives an answer that is useful to you don't forget to tick it. All the best.

Comment: noted!!! thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome ^^. I started to edit the beginning of your post to give you some hints on how to format with $\LaTeX$. See if you can use my example to reformat the rest of your question.

Comment: $(x+4)(x+2)\ne x^2+2x-8$. Did you mean $\frac{1}{x-2}$ in the original expression?

Answer (score 1):

The development you have in the question does not make sense, written the way you had originally. Better

\begin{gather}
\log_{3}(x+4) - \log_{3}\left(\frac{1}{x-2}\right) =  \ln e + \log_{6}36 \\[4px]
\log_3(x+4)(x-2) = 1 + 2
\\[4px]
\log_3(x+4)(x-2) = 3
\\[4px]
\log_3(x^2+2x-8) = 3
\\[4px]
3^3 = x^2+2x-8
\\[4px]
27 = x^2+2x-8
\\[4px]
x^2+2x-8-27 = 0
\\[4px]
x^2+2x-35 = 0
\\[4px]
(x+7)(x-5) = 0
\end{gather}
I fixed $2$ into $-2$ in lines 2 and 3.

The solutions of the last equation are indeed $-7$ and $5$, but the statement of the equation implies that you must have
$$
x+4>0,\qquad x-2>0
$$
so $-7$ cannot be a solution. The only one is $5$.

---

For the second equation, the easiest thing is to compute the logarithm in base $2$:
\begin{gather}
32^{2-2x} = (1/4)^{x^2-5}\\[6px]
(2-2x)\log_2 32=(x^2-5)\log_2(1/4)\\[6px]
(2-2x)\cdot 5=(x^2-5)\cdot(-2)
\end{gather}
that is a simple quadratic.

The solutions are $0$ and $5$, you're forgetting one: you can't divide by $-2x$.

Comment: More precisely, you can divide by $-2x$ if you assume that $-2x\ne0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Which you can't, in this case. Much better is to write $2x^2-10x=0$ so $2x(x-5)=0$, that shows the solutions.

Comment: Which you can: $-10x=-2x^2$ so that when $x\ne0$, $5=x$. $5=x$ is quite compatible with $x\ne0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Unfortunately, you can't assume $x\ne0$, because *it is* a root of the equation. I don't think that this way of solving equations is effective for beginners.

Comment: The method is 1) check if $x=0$ is a solution; 2) assuming $x\ne0$, solve the equation. There is no problem assuming $x\ne0$

Comment: @YvesDaoust Do you really think I don't know this? My concern is *teaching* it to beginners.

Comment: Yep, this is how you can teach it. No problem. Telling that you *may not* divide by $x$ is not just misleading, it is false.